# Error when importing data from Excel to SQL Server with CLR

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr, sqlbulkcopy

SQL DBA here, not a C# or a programmer guy. Below is some code I found online and tried to adapt to my needs:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures

{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]

    public static void ExcelTransfer(String FileName, String WorkBook, String TableName)

    {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("context connection = true"))

        {

            cn.Open();

            // Connection String to Excel Workbook

            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'";

            // Create Connection to Excel Workbook

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))

            {

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select Number FROM [" + WorkBook + "$]", connection);
                connection.Open();

                // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet

                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())

                {

                    // Bulk Copy to SQL Server

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))

                    {

                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;

                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

above code is registered in SQL Server with:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY ImportFromFile_XLS
FROM '<path to .dll>'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE procedure readExcel (@str1 nvarchar(255), @str2 nvarchar(255), @str3 nvarchar(255))
AS
EXTERNAL NAME ImportFromFile_XLS.StoredProcedures.ExcelTransfer
```

When I execute

```
EXEC dbo.readExcel 'C:\SQL_DATA\WorkBook.xls', 'WorkBook', 'testTable'
```

I get the error message:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.readExcel, Line 0 [Batch
> Start Line 46] A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of
> user-defined routine or aggregate "readExcel":
> System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation is not
> available on the context connection. System.InvalidOperationException:
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CreateOrValidateConnection(String
> method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32
> columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DbDataReader reader)
> at StoredProcedures.ExcelTransfer(String FileName, String WorkBook,
> String TableName) .

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [Context Connections and Regular Connections - Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/context-connections-and-regular-connections-restrictions): _The SqlBulkCopy class does not operate in a context connection._

Comment: First time I saw this, thank you. How should I then change "using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))" part? What is the way to copy the rows over?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to create a real connection string or don't use bulk but rather use regular inserts. It kinda sucks cause context connection is much more simpler

Comment: Worked after changing to a connection string. Had no idea a concept called as "context connection" existed and even were used in the file, just found the class definition online, I made the change upon your suggestion. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, `Context Connection` is not valid for using with `SqlBulkCopy`, as noted in the documentation — [Context Connections and Regular Connections - Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/context-connections-and-regular-connections-restrictions#restrictions-on-context-connections) (noted by @AlwaysLearning). A standard connection string is required.

HOWEVER, the documentation and comments are only partially correct. The Context Connection is only invalid for the *destination* connection. It is, on the other hand, valid for the *source* connection. That won't help here as the connection in question is the destination, but it should still be documented (and if I get a chance, I will update the Microsoft documentation to be more specific).

Comment: Thank you Solomon. Your blog posts and replies to other questions here helped me to sign the .dll and made it possible for the sp to work.

Answer (score 1):

No need in any CLR for your scenario. Just plain vanilla T-SQL.

The only precondition is that Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider needs to be installed. You need just one of the following three versions 12.0, 15.0, or 16.0.

The fully qualified path "*C:\SQL_DATA\WorkBook.xlsx*" is relative to the SQL Server instance server.

**T-SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
   'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;
    Database=C:\SQL_DATA\WorkBook.xlsx',
    [Sheet1$]);
```

Comment: I need to use CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection from `context connection` to a real connection string as per suggestions above from AlwaysLearning and siggemannen.